# Importing and merging GeoJSON files in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geojson, convert, merge, import

I have got a dataset of GeoJSON files (26000 polygons). This is the first time for me to work on GeoJSON format and I need to import all rectangles into QGIS, and crucially, I need to dissolve any touching rectangles into a single polygon *WITH A COUNT* of how many rectangles were dissolved into that polygon.

I need to be able to sort the merged resulting polygons by a number of former layers because it indicates relative importance. First of all, I thought that I should convert the GeoJSON into shapefile, but the process is too slow for too many polygons.

Comment: Are the rectangles all the same size? If so, calculate the count from the area of each polygon divided by the unit area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like that :

0. Don't charge the layers in your project. It will save you a lot of time.
1. Use the tool `mergevectorlayer` to merge all the geojson layer. You can select a folder directly to make this quick. If there is a bug due to the number of layer try to split the work in different folders.
2. Save your result on a layer in shp file or geopackage. (`layerA`)
3. Use tool `dissolve` to make a new layer with only one feature that will be a multipart geometry.
4. Use tool `multipartosinglepart` to separate the polygon that are not connected. You will get many feature that are disconnected one to another. Save this result (`layerB`).
5. Use tool `joinbylocationsummary` with `layerB` as source and `layerA` as layer to join. Select `count` as summary operation.

The End. Normally you will get as a result a layer that contain fusion of your connected features and for each, the number of source rectangles they are crossing.

Comment: Thank you very much @Corentin Lemaitre. I can't cast a vote, but your answer saved my day!

Comment: Hello @luisa, happy it did help. You can mark it as a solution i think.